# How do i create custom width columns with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have table with three cols that uses bootstrap class `"table table-striped"`. But i want first columns to be `100px` in length second `400px` and 3rd `200px`. How do i do this with bootstrapped tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th  style="width:100px !important;">Firstname</th>
        <th  style="width:400px !important;">Lastname</th>
        <th  style="width:200px !important;">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could give it another class like so `"table table-width-100 table-striped"`

and give the table-width-100 class the new width like so:

```
.table-width-100 { width: 100px; !important }
```

where !important overrides the default bootstrap css, but there might be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set width attribute to table headers for example `<th style="width: 500px">`

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is as follows:

1. Add a custom class to the `<table>`, so `<table class="table table-striped custom">` for example. This ensures you don't overwrite BootStrap's native styling.
2. Use the nth-child selector to programmatically select the 1st, 2nd and 3rd `<td>`'s in all rows, thus eliminating the need to add a different style to each `<td>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/gcxfxyx3/

The CSS for this particular case is:

```
    .custom td:nth-child(2) {
      width: 100px;
    }
    .custom td:nth-child(3) {
      width: 400px;
    }
    .custom td:nth-child(4) {
      width: 200px;
    }
```